# Javascript to Retrieve and store the value on Nth row Mth column

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting below response body from my post call in postman tool [image]

I did this:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var freeMem = '';
tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;
console.log(`API response:\n${responseBody}`);
var jsonItems = jsonData.commands;
_.each(jsonItems, function(var1) {

    if (var1.stdout !== undefined) {
        freeMem = `${var1.stdout}`;
        console.log(`API:\n${freeMem}`);

    }
});
```

Now under var freeMem I have this:- [image]

Now from this value i want to store the value of used Mem i.e 16150343680 and total Mem i.e 33569480704.

How to get this values

Comment: `I have stored the value of command - "free -kb" under variable Memory` - could you share the code you have written for this, as a starting point?

Comment: Don't know from where to start.

Comment: Well, for a start, you can't do this on a webpage, you can only get the result of `free -kb` if you're running something your Javascript on a server like `nodejs`. So perhaps start reading up on how to run a simple program on `nodejs`, and then look at how to [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) a command like `free` from it. That's assuming that not running this on a web page is not a deal breaker for you- there's no way for your web page to know how much memory any random visitor to your site has, if that's what you really want.

Comment: Actually this is the part of response body of my POST call. I am using postman tool. 
I tried this:-
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var freeMem = '';
tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;
console.log(`API response:\n${responseBody}`);
var jsonItems = jsonData.commands;
_.each(jsonItems, function(var1) {
    
    if (var1.stdout !== undefined) {
        freeMem = `${var1.stdout}`;
        console.log(`API:\n${freeMem}`);
//        postman.setEnvironmentVariable("freeMem", var1.stdout);
    }
});

Comment: Why not edit that into your question? And also the server side code? You have to give us  something to work with - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve